# How to join only on first record order by sequence

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I want to join two tables, and required all records from first one while only one from second (having sequence is lowest).
How to do that?

```
Template::join('template_id_recipes as tir', function ($join) {
    $join->on('templates.id', '=', 'tir.individual_process_id')
     ->where('tir.sequence', DB::raw("(select MIN('sequence') from template_ip_recipes)"));
})
->get();
```

I used:

```
->where('tir.sequence', DB::raw("(select MIN('sequence') from template_ip_recipes)"))
```

this condition to bring result but not able to do that.

DB Structure :
template_ip_recipes (table)
[image: DB Image]

Whenever I join to this table from templates table, I want record of id 17, but record with id 15 comes. How to get as required?

Comment: can you please share the table structure with some data and your expected output

Comment: share it in the question its not clear dude !!

Comment: @Manojkiran.A updated quastion. Kindly check.

Comment: can you share the parent table too it will be helpful for me to create the test instance

Comment: Parent table is "templates", and id is primary key of templates table.

Comment: if you only need one row, can't your do an  `ORDER BY sequence ASC LIMIT 1` ? or you need first line for multiple row return ?

Comment: I want only one line for each template.

Comment: If it was me, I'd start with 'raw' sql, and then, once that was working, re-arrange that to suit Laravel/Eloquent syntax.

Answer (score 0):

try 
DB::raw("MIN('template_ip_recipes.sequence'))

Comment: Gives Error : Invalid use of group function

Comment: try DB::havingRaw(("MIN('template_ip_recipes.sequence')")